# How to update a number without changing lines or placement of output

Tags: python, python-2.7

I would like to update a number without changing its placement in the output of a program. How would i go about doing this using only what is included in the standard library for python 2.7.2 ?

For example i want output like:

`working on: 9`

and change to:

`working on: 10`

without changing the line that it is displayed on. How would i go about doing this? I would also prefer that you not use `cls` as to prevent "flashing".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How to do this depends on your terminal type (and possibly on your platform).  An easy way that works on many platforms and terminals is to use a `\r` character to move the cursor back to the beginning of the line:

```
import time
import sys
for i in range(10):
    print "\rworking on:", i,
    sys.stdout.flush()
    time.sleep(1)
```

To make the line actually appear, you might need the call to `sys.stdout.flush()`.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't any easy way to do this without resorting to a GUI of some type. The standard way to create a GUI using the terminal is python's [curses](http://docs.python.org/library/curses.html) module. For an explanation of how to use curses in your application see: [Curses Programming with Python.](http://docs.python.org/howto/curses.html)